# Django Aggregation Get Count of Users per Project View

Tags: django, django-models, aggregation

I have a model for tracking users viewing a project, it has foreign key references to user and project. An example looks like

```
project user
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        2
```

What I want to achieve is a view count per projects so project 1 will be 3 and project 2 will be 2 in the example above.

I am trying below, but it counts every user instance, how do I get every user instance per project?

```
projects = ProjectViews.objects.all().annotate(view_count=Count('user'))
```

Comment: are "project" and "user" in same model?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
projects = ProjectViews.objects.annotate(view_count=Count('user')).values('id', 'view_count')
```

as output you should get:

```
[{'id': 1, 'view_count': 3}, {'id': 2, 'view_count': 2}]
```

Where 'id' is your `Project` `id`.

Comment: Thanks, will try this and let you know. I will need to get other values as well which was why I was using "objects", but I think I can work around it by selecting multiple values from such as 'project__name', 'project__description', for example.

Comment: This also gives me each project instance with a count of one next to it and not the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
projects = ProjectViews.objects.values('project').annotate(count=Count('user'))
```

this should work fine

Comment: This gives me each project instance with a count of one next to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
projects = ProjectViews.objects.values('project__id').annotate(view_count=Count('user__id',distinct=True)).values('view_count','project__id','project__name','project__owner__username','project__created','project__description').order_by("-view_count")[:10]
```

If anyone knows a better way to yield the same results then please let me know.